# Query to select records from multiple tables based on search criteria from UI

Tags: sql

I am trying to display results based on search criteria from UI. Search is performed in three tables and the tables are as below...

[image: Student Table]

[image: Subjects Table]

[image: Arrears Table]

The search criteria in the UI are Name, Number of Arrears, Arrear Subject in or / and condition. When some one enters J in name and click on search it will display student id 1 and 3. If the search criteria is Jill and English it should display all three arrears subjects (Algebra, English and Mathematics) instead of English alone...

Please find my query below:

```
select s.studentId
      ,s.FirstName
      ,s.LastName
      ,s.Department
      ,d.majorSubject
      ,a.Arrearsubject
from Student s, Department d, Arrear a
where ((:firstName is NULL OR upper (s.firstName) like upper(:firstName)||'%')
      or (:lastName is NULL OR upper (s.lastName) like upper(:lastName)||'%') and (:arrearSubject is NULL OR a.arrearID :=arrearSubject) 
and s.studentID = a.studentID and s.studentID = d.studentID;
```

While passing the arrearSubject from UI to data base i will pick up the related arrear ID and do my search based on that. Here in the above query arrearSubject is what user see and enter, and the value to query is just its id.

Table/ Query is in Mainframe/ DB2. I am more into UI/ UX/ Java/ J2EE. Please apologies if there are any mistakes in the query or my question is very basic.

Comment: This looks like different queries and results depending on what is entered. Or do you want to have the same result structure and then display different parts of it depending on what data is returned?

Comment: An example of a resultset always helps - how do you want the Arrear Subject appear in the result - three rows or all in a single column?

Comment: Hello, Please find the sample expected result set as below:  (I want three rows, basically diff rows for each record...)          
StudentID FirstName LastName Department Major subject ArrearSubject
1 Jack  JJ Physics Quantum Physics English
1 Jack  JJ Physics Quantum Physics Mechanics
3 Jill JI Mathematics Trignometry Algebra
3 Jill JI Mathematics Trignometry English
3 Jill JI Mathematics Trignometry Mechanics